# Why is indiscrete topology unmetrizable?

Tags: general-topology

> For instance, the indiscrete topology for $X$ cannot arise from a metric when $X$ has more than one point. One way to see this is to note that the complement of a one-point set in a metric space is always open.

I don't see what is going on here. Say $X=\{a,b\}$. Then the indiscrete topology for $X$ would be $\mathfrak{F}=\{\emptyset,X \}$. But now what?

Comment: An indiscrete space has precisely two distinct open sets. A metric space with two or more points has at least four.

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Metric_space note the definition, Given 2 points we know that $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$ so $d(a,b)>0$ - this confirms the above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do now is assume there exists a metric $d$, and derive a contradiction.  For instance, if $X = \{a,b\}$, then there is some distance $D = d(a,b) > 0$.  What can you now say about the (open) ball of radius $D$ centered at $a$?  In other words, which points $x\in X$ satisfy $d(a,x) < D = d(a,b)$?

Comment: Eh, no point will satisfy that condition? But why would that be a contradiction? Is is because we would have an open set of $X$ that's not in the topology we defined?

Comment: Note that $a$ satisfies it since $d(a,a) = 0$ by the definition of metric.  You are correct that a contradiction will be reached if you can show that there exists an open set that isn't $\emptyset$ or $X$

Comment: OK, but how would $d(a,a)=0$ give us the contradiction?

Comment: It would show that the set $\{a\}$ is an open ball, and thus an open set.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. I thought that a singleton is closed in metric space?

Comment: Singletons are both closed and open in finite metric spaces.  Note that if you prove singletons are closed in metric spaces, you immediately show that indiscrete spaces aren't metrizable.

Comment: @Misakov Alternatively, if you know that singletons are closed in a metric space, then since $\{b\}$ is closed, $X\setminus\{b\}=\{a\}$ is open.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, and let $x\in X$. If $y$ is any other point of $X$, then $d(x,y)>0$. Let $r_y=d(x,y)$; then $B_d(y,r_y)$ is an open ball about $y$ that does not contain $x$. Now let

$$U=\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}B_d(y,r_y)\;.$$

- $U$ is a union of open balls, so $U$ is open.
- If $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, then $y\in B_d(y,r_y)\subseteq U$, so $U\supseteq X\setminus\{x\}$.
- For all $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, $x\notin B_d(y,r_y)$, so $x\notin U$.

The last two points show that $U=X\setminus\{x\}$; couple that with the first, and you see that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open. In other words, we’ve just proved the claim that you quoted:

> the complement of a one-point set in a metric space is open.

Now apply that to your space $X=\{a,b\}$ with the indiscrete topology $\{\varnothing,X\}$: $\{a\}$ is a one-point subset of $X$, and its complement is $\{b\}$, which is not open. Therefore the topology on $X$ cannot come from any metric. And the same argument works for the indiscrete topology on any set with more than one point.