# Least Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a nonempty set. Is there always a metric on $S$ such that the induced topology is $\{∅, S\}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is indiscrete topology unmetrizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252095/why-is-indiscrete-topology-unmetrizable)

Answer (score 1):

No. There is one precisely when $\vert S \vert \leq 1$.

Assume $\vert S \vert > 1$. Then pick $x,y \in S$ and let $r := d(x,y)$. Then we have $B_{r/2}(x) = \{x\} \neq S$ open.

Comment: Or perhaps stating in another way that a topological space has to be Hausdorff in order for its topology to be induced by a metric.